# Find sum of numbers in a string without loops in c++

Tags: c++

I've found plenty of resources online how how to calculate the sum of numbers in an alphanumeric string, and I've got a working c++ code below.

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 
  
int findSum(string str) 
{ 
    string temp = ""; 
    int sum = 0; 
    for (char ch: str) 
    { 
        if (isdigit(ch)) 
            temp += ch; 
        else
        { 
            sum += atoi(temp.c_str()); 
            temp = ""; 
        } 
    } 
    return sum + atoi(temp.c_str()); 
} 
  
int main() 
{ 
    string str = "t35t5tr1ng"; 
  
    cout << findSum(str); 
  
    return 0; 
}
```

For the example above, **"t35t5tr1ng"** returns **"41"**.
Now I'm trying to do the same thing, **without using any loops**.

On the top of my head, I'm thinking arrays, but even then I'm not sure how to parse the values in the array without a for loop of some kind.
Any suggestions or help would be appreciated!

Comment: *I've found plenty of resources online* -- None of these "online resources" discussed `std::accumulate`?

Comment: Is this a "just to see if I can" thing? Most recommendations will just be Standard Library functions, and there's a good chance that they're only abstracting the loops. To use a tool belt analogy, this is like looking straight at a nail and going "How can I get this nail into the wood, **without a hammer?**"

Comment: @sweenish to extend your analogy, essentially the answer is to hire someone else to use a hammer for you. Unfortunately OP, if you need to search for something in a string, an array, a vector, whatever, there will be a loop involved at one point or another.

Comment: Do it recursively?

Comment: Note: You can get the numerical value of any digit by subtracting `'0'`. This make accumulating a string and then using `atoi` unnecessary. You could instead `val = val * 10 + ch - '0';`. Remember to set `val` back to zero after adding it to the sum.

Answer (score 2):

You can use standard algorithms instead of writing loops. Even if it's just a for-loop under the hood, but it can make user code easier to understandby stating the intent.

```cpp
int findSum(string str) 
{ 
    // replace all the non-digits with spaces
    std::replace_if(str.begin(), str.end(),
      [](unsigned char c) {
          return !std::isdigit(c);
      }, ' ');
      
    // sum up space separated numbers
    std::istringstream iss{str};  
    return std::accumulate(
      std::istream_iterator<int>{iss}, 
      std::istream_iterator<int>{}, 0);
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7bv7WJ).

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution using [std::accumulate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate):

```
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

int findSum(std::string str) 
{ 
    int curVal = 0;
    return std::accumulate(str.begin(), str.end(), 0, [&](int total, char ch)
    { 
       // build up the number if it's a digit 
       if (std::isdigit(static_cast<int>(ch))) 
           curVal = 10 * curVal + (ch - '0');  
       else
       {
         // add the number and reset the built up number to 0
         total += curVal;
         curVal = 0;
       } 
       return total;
     });
  }

int main() 
{ 
    std::string str = "t35t5tr1ng"; 
    std::cout << findSum(str); 
    return 0; 
}
```